# Error: can't insert data into SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert data into my database called "Flujo_Efectivo", on the table "Entrada_Datos" using C# on Visual Studio Community 2017. The program is supposed to save the data when a button is pressed. This is my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) ==
            DialogResult.OK)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString: @"Data Source = ACER\SQLEXPRESS2016; Initial Catalog = Flujo_Efectivo; Integrated Security = True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText: "INSERT INTO Entrada_Datos(Description,Quantity (Gs.),Quantity (USD)) VALUES (@Description,@Quantity (Gs.),@Quantity (USD))", connection: con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@Description", value: textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@Quantity (Gs.)", value: textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@Quantity (USD)", value: textBox3.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show(text: "The changes have been saved", caption: "Notification"); 
                }
    }
```

However, the following error appears:

> "system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception: incorrect syntax near ')'"

I checked every ')' on my query and I can't find anything that could cause something like this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have spaces in your column names in your Database Flujo_Efectivo? For example have you named a Column in Table "Entrada_Datos" the Column Name "Quantity (Gs.)" ?

Comment: "Are you shure..." should be "Are you sure..."

Comment: As a general suggestion, whenever you are trying to run some SQL in C#, try it in your SQL tooling (Management Studio) etc first. There you should have received the same error (since your column name has spaces in it).

Comment: Unrelated tip: The SqlConnection and SqlCommand are disposable, so put them in a using block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have spaces or characters like ( in your `SqlParameter` names. And wrap column names that have spaces in `[]`

```
INSERT INTO Entrada_Datos(Description,[Quantity (Gs.)],[Quantity (USD)]) VALUES (@Description,@QuantityGs,@QuantityUsd)
```

And then also rename them accordingly where you are assigning values:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@Description", value: textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@QuantityGs", value: textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName: "@QuantityUsd", value: textBox3.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            // you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = adres;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(@"Data Added");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Connection Failed");
        }
```